# Get Percentile for a user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table such as this:

```
Id, ReportId, UserId  
1      1        1  
2      2        1  
3      3        1
4      4        1
5      1        2
6      2        2
7      3        2
8      1        3
9      2        3
10     1        4
```

My table has thousands of records, above is just an example of the table structure simplified for purpose of understanding the problem.

I'm trying to figure out what at what percentile a user sits based on how many reports he has read.

I've been looking into PERCENTILE_CONT and PERCENTILE_DISC functions, but I fail to understand them properly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql

What confuses me most is that what it appears to me is that these functions are trying to find the 50th percentile, not percentile for a specific record.

Maybe I'm just not understanding this correctly. Is there a better way?

EDIT:

To clarify. I want to know at what percentile a specific user (in this case user with id 1) sits based on how many reports they have read. If they read the most reports they would be at a higher percentile, what is that percentile? Lets say there are 100 users exactly, then the person with most reports read would be 1st percentile.

Comment: All your users  have read one report, so this sample data leaves something to be desired.

Comment: What is "*percentile for a specific record*" supposed to mean?

Comment: again what is percentile? You says the one with more reports is 1st percentil. What about ties? What about the last one? is just an order from 1 to 100 ? Show us what result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update #2

One of these should do it:

```
select 
        a.UserId, 
        a.reports_read, 
        PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.reports_read) OVER (partition by UserId) AS percentile_d, 
        PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.reports_read) OVER (partition by UserId) AS percentile_c,
        PERCENT_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY a.reports_read ) percent_rank,
        CUME_DIST() OVER(ORDER BY a.reports_read ) AS cumulative_distance     
    from 
        (select UserId, count(distinct(ReportId)) as reports_read
            from #tmp
            group by UserId
        ) a
```

It gives the following results:

```
UserId  reports_read    percentile_d    percentile_c    percent_rank    cumulative_distance
4       1               1               1               0               0.25
3       2               2               2               0.33333         0.5
2       3               3               3               0.66667         0.75
1       6               6               6               1               1
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Tried your example, but the voracious_reader_percentile always comes back as 2. With your example, how would you modify it to find user with id 1, at what percentile he is based on total reads?

Comment: UPDATED - @Bojan -  I added a Partition By and changed the column names to match yours and tested it (actually created your table).

Comment: With your example, how would you modify it to find user with id 1, at what percentile he is based on total reads?

Comment: I ran this again against my table and the voracious_reader_percentile is always the same as reports_read value

Comment: UPDATE #2 - @Bojan - I added cumulative_distance because I thought it might be what you want.

Comment: @Bojan - ...and PERCENT_RANK (my money's on that one!)

Comment: Actually, I think its the CUME_DIST(). Looking at the data that came back to me, percent rank gives me a 0 for the last x amount of users that have 1 report read. Where as the CUME_DIST tells me 0.37. I need to do more testing to be sure

Comment: @Bojan - I added my results (I gave User 1 two more reports in my data) to the answer.  If this helps you, don't forget to 'Accept' it as the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I had to do the testing and I'm very satisfied with the results. The PERCENT_RANK is the key.